# How to install fontawesome.sharp icons in Visual Studio 2015, I'm building a Windows form and need fontawesome.sharp tools

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015, font-awesome, nuget-package

I'm building a windows form in Visual Studio 2015, I'm trying to add font-awesome.sharp tools in my project. I've installed font-awesome.sharp using NuGet package manager but it doesn't add it to my tools menu.

I tried to find some .dll file for it but can't find the correct file. How can I do the installation?

Comment: Font awesome icons were used in winforms app, here is the link of youtube video in which he used fontawesome.sharp in winforms. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5AsJJl7Bhvc&t=11s

I just don't know why I am not able to install it properly.

Answer (score -1):

you can find the dll file (FontAwesome.Sharp.dll) in (YourProjectFolder\packages\FontAwesome.Sharp.5.15.1\lib\net40)